# Transform a HList of Eithers to an Either of a HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to define a function that accepts a `HList` whose elements are such that, for each element `t`, there is a type `T` such that `t: Either[String, T]`. The function, which we will call `validate`, should have the following behaviour:

- If all elements of the parameter are `Right`, return `Right` of the result of mapping the parameter with right-projection.
- Otherwise, return a `Left[List[String]]`, where the list contains the left-projection for each `Left` in the parameter.

Examples:

```
validate (Right (42) :: Right (3.14) :: Right (false) :: HNil)
>> Right (42 :: 3.14 :: false :: HNil)
```

```
validate (Right (42) :: Left ("qwerty") :: Left ("uiop") :: HNil)
>> Left (List ("qwerty", "uiop"))
```

An example use case:

```
case class Result (foo: Foo, bar: Bar, baz: Baz, qux: Qux)

def getFoo: Either[String, Foo] = ???
def getBar: Either[String, Bar] = ???
def getBaz: Either[String, Baz] = ???
def getQux: Either[String, Qux] = ???

def createResult: Either[String, Result] = {
    validate (getFoo :: getBar :: getBaz :: getQux :: HNil) match {
        case Right (foo :: bar :: baz :: qux :: HNil) => Right (Result (foo, bar, baz, qux))
        case Left (errors) => Left ("The following errors occurred:\n" + errors.mkString ("\n"))
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to get what you want by right-folding an HList with a `Poly`, but I honestly recommend to look into how validation is done in FP, e.g. [in cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume we have some test data like this throughout this answer:

```
scala> import shapeless.{::, HNil}
import shapeless.{$colon$colon, HNil}

scala> type In = Either[String, Int] :: Either[String, String] :: HNil
defined type alias In

scala> val good: In = Right(123) :: Right("abc") :: HNil
good: In = Right(123) :: Right(abc) :: HNil

scala> val bad: In = Left("error 1") :: Left("error 2") :: HNil
bad: In = Left(error 1) :: Left(error 2) :: HNil
```

### Using a custom type class

There are many ways you could do this. I'd probably use a custom type class that highlights the way instances are built up inductively:

```
import shapeless.HList

trait Sequence[L <: HList] {
  type E
  type Out <: HList
  def apply(l: L): Either[List[E], Out]
}

object Sequence {
  type Aux[L <: HList, E0, Out0 <: HList] = Sequence[L] { type E = E0; type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def hnilSequence[E0]: Aux[HNil, E0, HNil] = new Sequence[HNil] {
    type E = E0
    type Out = HNil
    def apply(l: HNil): Either[List[E], HNil] = Right(l)
  }

  implicit def hconsSequence[H, T <: HList, E0](implicit
    ts: Sequence[T] { type E = E0 }
  ): Aux[Either[E0, H] :: T, E0, H :: ts.Out] = new Sequence[Either[E0, H] :: T] {
    type E = E0
    type Out = H :: ts.Out
    def apply(l: Either[E0, H] :: T): Either[List[E0], H :: ts.Out] =
      (l.head, ts(l.tail)) match {
        case (Right(h), Right(t)) => Right(h :: t)
        case (Left(eh), Left(et)) => Left(eh :: et)
        case (Left(eh), _) => Left(List(eh))
        case (_, Left(et)) => Left(et)
      }
  }
}
```

Then you can write `validate` like this:

```
def validate[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit s: Sequence[L]): Either[List[s.E], s.Out] = s(l)
```

And use it like this:

```
scala> validate(good)
res0: scala.util.Either[List[String],Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Right(123 :: abc :: HNil)

scala> validate(bad)
res1: scala.util.Either[List[String],Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Left(List(error 1, error 2))
```

Note that the static types come out right.

### Using a right fold

You could also do it a little more concisely by folding with a `Poly2`.

```
import shapeless.Poly2

object combine extends Poly2 {
  implicit def eitherCase[H, T, E, OutT <: HList]:
    Case.Aux[Either[E, H], Either[List[E], OutT], Either[List[E], H :: OutT]] = at {
      case (Right(h), Right(t)) => Right(h :: t)
      case (Left(eh), Left(et)) => Left(eh :: et)
      case (Left(eh), _) => Left(List(eh))
      case (_, Left(et)) => Left(et) 
    }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> good.foldRight(Right(HNil): Either[List[String], HNil])(combine)
res2: scala.util.Either[List[String],Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Right(123 :: abc :: HNil)

scala> bad.foldRight(Right(HNil): Either[List[String], HNil])(combine)
res3: scala.util.Either[List[String],Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Left(List(error 1, error 2))
```

I guess this is probably the "right" answer, assuming you want to stick to Shapeless alone. The `Poly2` approach just relies on some weird details of implicit resolution (we couldn't define `combine` as a `val`, for example) that I personally don't really like.

### Using Kittens's sequence

Lastly you could use the [Kittens](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens) library, which supports sequencing and traversing hlists:

```
scala> import cats.instances.all._, cats.sequence._
import cats.instances.all._
import cats.sequence._

scala> good.sequence
res4: scala.util.Either[String,Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Right(123 :: abc :: HNil)

scala> bad.sequence
res5: scala.util.Either[String,Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Left(error 1)
```

Note that this doesn't accumulate errors, though.

If you wanted the most complete possible Typelevel experience I guess you could add a `parSequence` operation to Kittens that would accumulate errors for an hlist of eithers via the `Parallel` instance mapping them to `Validated` (see [my blog post here](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2019/09/11/why-parallel/) for more detail about how this works). Kittens doesn't currently include this, though.

### Update: parallel sequencing

If you want `parSequence`, it's not actually *that* much of a nightmare to write it yourself:

```
import shapeless.HList, shapeless.poly.~>, shapeless.ops.hlist.{Comapped, NatTRel}
import cats.Parallel, cats.instances.all._, cats.sequence.Sequencer

def parSequence[L <: HList, M[_], P[_], PL <: HList, Out](l: L)(implicit
  cmp: Comapped[L, M],
  par: Parallel.Aux[M, P],
  ntr: NatTRel[L, M, PL, P],
  seq: Sequencer.Aux[PL, P, Out]
): M[Out] = {
  val nt = new (M ~> P) {
    def apply[A](a: M[A]): P[A] = par.parallel(a)
  }

  par.sequential(seq(ntr.map(nt, l)))
}
```

And then:

```
scala> parSequence(good)
res0: Either[String,Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Right(123 :: abc :: HNil)

scala> parSequence(bad)
res1: Either[String,Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Left(error 1error 2)
```

Note that this *does* accumulate errors, but by concatenating the strings. The Cats-idiomatic way to accumulate errors in a list would look like this:

```
scala> import cats.syntax.all._
import cats.syntax.all._

scala> val good = 123.rightNel[String] :: "abc".rightNel[String] :: HNil
good: Either[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],Int] :: Either[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],String] :: shapeless.HNil = Right(123) :: Right(abc) :: HNil

scala> val bad = "error 1".leftNel[String] :: "error 2".leftNel[Int] :: HNil
bad: Either[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],String] :: Either[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],Int] :: shapeless.HNil = Left(NonEmptyList(error 1)) :: Left(NonEmptyList(error 2)) :: HNil

scala> parSequence(good)
res3: Either[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil] = Right(123 :: abc :: HNil)

scala> parSequence(bad)
res4: Either[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],String :: Int :: shapeless.HNil] = Left(NonEmptyList(error 1, error 2))
```

It'd probably be worth opening a PR to add something like this to Kittens.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to arrive at a solution essentially identical to Travis Brown's right-fold solution, with a few additions:

```scala
class Validate[E] {
    def apply[L <: HList] (hlist: L) (implicit folder: RightFolder[L, Either[List[E], HNil], combine.type]) =
        hlist.foldRight (Right (HNil) : Either[List[E], HNil]) (combine)
}

object combine extends Poly2 {
    implicit def combine[E, H, T <: HList]
    : ProductCase.Aux[Either[E, H] :: Either[List[E], T] :: HNil, Either[List[E], H :: T]] = use {
        (elem: Either[E, H], result: Either[List[E], T]) => (elem, result) match {
            case (Left (error), Left (errors)) => Left (error :: errors)
            case (Left (error), Right (_)) => Left (error :: Nil)
            case (Right (_), Left (errors)) => Left (errors)
            case (Right (value), Right (values)) => Right (value :: values)
        }
    }
}

def validate[E] = new Validate[E]
```

This allows the left type to vary, and allows the syntax:

```scala
validate[String] (getFoo :: getBar :: getBaz :: getQux :: HNil) match {
    case Right (foo :: bar :: baz :: qux :: HNil) => ???
    case Left (errors) => ???
}
```

Admittedly this is the first time that I have used `Poly`. It blew my mind to see that this actually worked. Infuriatingly, the static analysis provided by my IDE (IntelliJ) is not clever enough to infer the types of the terms in the match cases.